# VBA code not correcting dates for all rows of data

Tags: vba, excel, date

I hope you can help. I have a piece of code and it works relatively well.

What it does is it opens up a dialog box using a command button that allows a user to select another excel sheet once this sheet is selected the code then consolidates the duplicates and creates a new row with the earliest possible start date and latest possible end date then deletes the duplicate rows.

So in Pic 1

We can see that we have duplicate rows with multiple start date and end dates what the code should do is find the duplicates with the earliest start date and latest end date and make a new line.

Pic 1.

[image: Pic1]

In Pic 2 
you can see that the duplicates have been removed and for the first duplicate the dates are correct with the earliest start date and latest end date possible available Agnholt Jørgen Steen Start date 01/04/2016  end date 17/06/2016

But for Breum   Leif its the wrong way round 04/05/2016 13/01/2016

Pic 2. 
[image]

Can my code be amended to solve this issue. As always any help is greatly appreciated.

My code is below.

CODE

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()


    Dim strFileName     As String
    Dim wkb             As Workbook
    Dim wks             As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow         As Long
    Dim r               As Long

    MsgBox "Select Denmark File" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

        strFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

    Set wkb = Application.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
    Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lastRow = wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For r = lastRow To 3 Step -1
        ' Identify Duplicate
        If wks.Cells(r, 1) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 1) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 2) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 2) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 3) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 3) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 4) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 4) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 5) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 5) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 6) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 6) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 7) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 7) Then
            ' Update Start Date on Previous Row
            If wks.Cells(r, 8) < wks.Cells(r - 1, 8) Then
                wks.Cells(r - 1, 8) = wks.Cells(r, 8)
            End If
            ' Update End Date on Previous Row
            If wks.Cells(r, 9) > wks.Cells(r - 1, 9) Then
                wks.Cells(r - 1, 9) = wks.Cells(r, 9)
            End If
            ' Delete Duplicate
            Rows(r).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `04/05/2016` is 4th May 2016?

Comment: I assume the values in columns H and I are text, not dates.  Is that correct?  (And it is therefore setting column H to be the lowest text value, i.e. `"04/05/2016"` is less than `"13/01/2016"` because `"0"` is less than `"1"`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your output, it appears that the cells in column H and I are text, not dates.  Thus `"04/05/2016"` is less than `"13/01/2016"`, and (for Anders Nyboe Andersen) `"15/03/2016"` is greater than `"14/03/2016"` is greater than `"07/04/2016"`.

Providing your locale settings are such that dates are represented as "dd/mm/yyyy" format (your profile says Ireland, so I am guessing that they are), you can get your tests working by converting the text in the cells to be a `Date` prior to performing your comparisons:

```
' Update Start Date on Previous Row
If CDate(wks.Cells(r, 8)) < CDate(wks.Cells(r - 1, 8)) Then
    wks.Cells(r - 1, 8) = wks.Cells(r, 8)
End If
' Update End Date on Previous Row
If CDate(wks.Cells(r, 9)) > CDate(wks.Cells(r - 1, 9)) Then
    wks.Cells(r - 1, 9) = wks.Cells(r, 9)
End If
```

Comment: Hi YowE3k: That was it. It was stored as Text. Thank you so much for the help the code you gave me worked perfectly. Thank you so much for taking the time. Much respect from Dublin :-) Have a great day